# Can't retrieve values from a ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: python, django

I've read the documentation for the QuerySet API and some answers here but I can't seem to figure this out. I think I'm not understanding the concept behind this.

So, this is my the models.py:

```
class Categoria(models.Model):
    TODOS = 'Todos'
    VEICULO = 'Veiculo'
    EQUIPAMENTO = 'Equipamento'
    SERVICO = 'Servico'
    OUTRO = 'Outro'

    CATEOGRY_CHOICES = (
        (TODOS, 'Todos'),
        (VEICULO, 'Veiculo'),
        (EQUIPAMENTO, 'Equipamento'),
        (SERVICO, 'Servico'),
        (OUTRO, 'Outro')
    )

    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=CATEOGRY_CHOICES, default=TODOS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tipo

class Anuncio(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    anuncio = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    preco = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    contato = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publicacao = models.DateTimeField()

    categoria = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

Then, I send this dictionary to the view:

```
{ 'anuncios' : Anuncio.objects.all()
```

And this is how I display the values:

```
{% for item in anuncios %}

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <h3>{{ item.titulo }}</h3>
                <p>{{ item.anuncio }}</p>
                <address>{{ item.contato }}</address>
                <h6><a href="#">{{ item.categoria.all.values }}</a></h6>
            </div>
        </div>

{% endfor %}
```

But I can't get the right value from that ManyToManyField. If I use `item.categoria`, I get `lista.Categoria.None` (lista is the name of the app). If I use `item.categoria.all`, I get `<QuerySet [<Categoria: Servico>]>`.
And if I use `item.categoria.all.values`, I get `<QuerySet [{'id': 7, 'tipo': 'Servico'}]>`. All I really want, in this case, is the 'Servico' word.

Also, if I try to filter something, I get `TemplateSyntaxError at /`with the message `Could not parse the remainder:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *many*-to-many relationship. There is not just one category, but many; so you can't just access the "Servicio", because you might have multiple items. You need to iterate through:

```
{% for cat in item.categoria.all %}{{ cat.tipo }}{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this when I was learning Django..

I dont know if its a typo or in your actual code but you are missing the closing '}'

you have:

```
{ 'anuncios' : Anuncio.objects.all()
```

it should be:

```
{ 'anuncios' : Anuncio.objects.all() }
```

but you should include the view code with your example.

if you are getting this.. it is returning the object.

```
<QuerySet [<Categoria: Servico>]>
```

you should be doing

```
item.categoria.tipo
```

to get a specific value of the tip to display for each item in your template. But it will display each choice selected for the "tipo" of each item.

If you only want the template to display only items with "Servico" you have to change either the query search in your context dictionary to a more specific query, or within the template with something like:

```
{%if item.categoria.tipo == 'Servico'%}
    #enter template code
{%endif%}
```

Comment: and Daniel Roseman's example above mine is much better and cleaner. lol